# How do I initially give my ERC20 tokens back to myself when deploying to mainnet

Tags: remix, erc-20, ropsten

I have successfully deployed my tokens to Ropsten testnet and was able to supply them to myself by adding the contract address manually in metamask. 
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x681fa70eef4e3411a07469c820497b74c2fe527b72f0d0b1f2e4679f097dd6a4

I am able to send my tokens back and forth to any address on Ropsten without issue. However when I deploy to mainnet I have none of my own tokens in my mainnet wallet view to share with others. How do I give tokens to self when deploying to mainnet. Like a premine or airdrop logic? Here's the source code I am using for both test and main"

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
    contract Ballot {

    struct Voter {
        uint weight;
        bool voted;
        uint8 vote;
        address delegate;
    }
    struct Proposal {
        uint voteCount;
    }

    address chairperson;
    mapping(address => Voter) voters;
    Proposal[] proposals;

    /// Create a new ballot with $(_numProposals) different proposals.
    function Ballot(uint8 _numProposals) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;
        proposals.length = _numProposals;
    }

    /// Give $(toVoter) the right to vote on this ballot.
    /// May only be called by $(chairperson).
    function giveRightToVote(address toVoter) public {
        if (msg.sender != chairperson || voters[toVoter].voted) return;
        voters[toVoter].weight = 1;
    }

    /// Delegate your vote to the voter $(to).
    function delegate(address to) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender]; // assigns reference
        if (sender.voted) return;
        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0) && voters[to].delegate != msg.sender)
            to = voters[to].delegate;
        if (to == msg.sender) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Voter storage delegateTo = voters[to];
        if (delegateTo.voted)
            proposals[delegateTo.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        else
            delegateTo.weight += sender.weight;
    }

    /// Give a single vote to proposal $(toProposal).
    function vote(uint8 toProposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (sender.voted || toProposal >= proposals.length) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = toProposal;
        proposals[toProposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    function winningProposal() public constant returns (uint8 _winningProposal) {
        uint256 winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint8 prop = 0; prop < proposals.length; prop++)
            if (proposals[prop].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[prop].voteCount;
                _winningProposal = prop;
            }
    }
    }

    contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
    }

    contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    }

    contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
    }


    contract Owned {
    address public owner;
    address public newOwner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

    function Owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        newOwner = _newOwner;
    }
    function acceptOwnership() public {
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
        OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
        newOwner = address(0);
    }
 }

contract MyTestToken is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath {
string public symbol;
string public  name;
uint8 public decimals;
uint public _totalSupply;

mapping(address => uint) balances;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

function MyTestToken() public {
    symbol = "MTT";
    name = "My Test Token";
    decimals = 10;
    _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;
    balances[0x8f32827Aa1FbbD4915E2592B8D77F762F9412db3] = _totalSupply;
    Transfer(address(0), 0x8f32827Aa1FbbD4915E2592B8D77F762F9412db3, _totalSupply);
}

function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
    return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
}

function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[tokenOwner];
}

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}

function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
    Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
    allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    Transfer(from, to, tokens);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {
    return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
}

function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
    Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
    ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
    return true;
}

function () public payable {
    revert();
}

function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
    return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code transfers the tokens to the 0x8f32827...... address

```
 Transfer(address(0), 0x8f32827Aa1FbbD4915E2592B8D77F762F9412db3, _totalSupply);
 }
```

Replace the address with your eth address.

```
Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
  }
```

is the best way to do so. It transfers the tokens to the contract creator.

I'd advise you use the Open Zeppelin framework. 
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity

You do not need the below codes. Delete them.

```
contract Ballot {

    struct Voter {
        uint weight;
        bool voted;
        uint8 vote;
        address delegate;
    }
    struct Proposal {
        uint voteCount;
    }

    address chairperson;
    mapping(address => Voter) voters;
    Proposal[] proposals;

    /// Create a new ballot with $(_numProposals) different proposals.
    function Ballot(uint8 _numProposals) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;
        proposals.length = _numProposals;
    }

    /// Give $(toVoter) the right to vote on this ballot.
    /// May only be called by $(chairperson).
    function giveRightToVote(address toVoter) public {
        if (msg.sender != chairperson || voters[toVoter].voted) return;
        voters[toVoter].weight = 1;
    }

    /// Delegate your vote to the voter $(to).
    function delegate(address to) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender]; // assigns reference
        if (sender.voted) return;
        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0) && voters[to].delegate != msg.sender)
            to = voters[to].delegate;
        if (to == msg.sender) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Voter storage delegateTo = voters[to];
        if (delegateTo.voted)
            proposals[delegateTo.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        else
            delegateTo.weight += sender.weight;
    }

    /// Give a single vote to proposal $(toProposal).
    function vote(uint8 toProposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (sender.voted || toProposal >= proposals.length) return;
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = toProposal;
        proposals[toProposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    function winningProposal() public constant returns (uint8 _winningProposal) {
        uint256 winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint8 prop = 0; prop < proposals.length; prop++)
            if (proposals[prop].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[prop].voteCount;
                _winningProposal = prop;
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I see get rid of the Ballot logic if I'm not using that. Also I thought that by sending to  `0x8f32827...... address` which is my metamask wallet address it would send the `INITIAL_SUPPLY` to me which is the contract creator. 

So the 3 params that in the transfer method the only one that I don't understand is the `0x0`. Is that a default value that appends itself somewhere in the submission logic of the contract?

Thanks again for all the help.